# Getting error while calling generator in Python

Tags: python, generator, yield

I created a simple generator:

```
def long_time():

    for i in range(10):

        yield i * 5  

a = long_time()

print(next(a))

print(next(a))
```

Here, I get the outputs 0 and 5, which is OK. But when I try to build the variable a as below:

```
def long_time():

    for i in range(10):
        yield i * 5
  
a = long_time

print(next(a()))

print(next(a()))
```

Both of the print outputs are 0. What is the difference, should I always call the generator with ()?

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
a = long_time
```

you're just giving a different name to the function `long_time`.

So writing

```
print(next(a()))
```

is the same as writing

```
print(next(long_time()))
```

That is, in a single line, you get a generator object by calling `long_time()`, then pass it to `next`, getting the generator's first value `0`. But since you don't have a reference to that generator, after that line you can't access the object anymore. On your next `print...` line, you're getting a fresh generator since it involves a new call to `long_time()`.

This is fixed when `a` isn't a reference to the `long_time` function, but its return value (the generator) instead:

```
a = long_time()
```

Comment: So even though, if I say a = long_time(), next(a) is still something else (return value) than next(long_time()). It is a bit confusing though...

Comment: The returned value is the same, the difference is whether you have a reference to it (i.e. store it in a variable) or not, so you can access it later on. It's like writing `[1, 2, 3][0]` versus `mylist = [1, 2, 3]; mylist[0]`: in both cases you get the first element of a list, but in the first example you don't have access to the list afterwards because you created it and extracted its first element in a single line. `next_long_time())` is like the former, `a = long_time(); next(a)` is like the latter.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `long_time`, you get back a fresh generator object. In your second example, `a` is just another name for the generator *function*, so each time you call `a()`, you get a new generator (just as if you had called `long_time`) that starts at 0.